# how do you set up a sqlalchemy relationsihp, such that the subqueryload will filter our results based on an attribute

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following sqlalchemy models/tables:

```
Table('tableA',
    MetaData(bind=None),
    Column('id', BigInteger()),
    Column('deleted', Boolean())
    schema=None)

Table('tableA_tableB',
    MetaData(bind=None),
    Column('tableB', BigInteger(), ForeignKey('tableB.id'), table=<tableA_tableB>),
    Column('tableA', BigInteger(), ForeignKey('tableA.id'), table=<tableA_tableB>),
    schema=None)

Table('tableB',
    MetaData(bind=None),
    Column('id', BigInteger()),
    Column('deleted', Boolean())
    schema=None)
```

There is a `one-to-many` relationship that is created by the following code:

```
self.db.relationship("tableB", secondary=tableA_tableB)
```

This works as expected when running a subqueryload, it returns all the joined results.  However, now I need to set up the relationship so that it only returns children where deleted is not True.

I attempted to use the `primaryjoin` keyword in the relationship function, but I am making little to no headway.

```
self.db.relationship("tableB",
    primaryjoin='and_(tableB.id==tableA_tableB.tableB,
                      tableB.deleted.isnot(True))',
    secondary=tableA_tableB)
```

My thought was that because I am using a secondary table, the secondaryjoin could be the default, and I would only need to adjust the primaryjoin. But it didn't appear to do anything.

Here is the query that is being generated:

```
SELECT tableB.deleted AS tableB_deleted,
       anon_1.tableA_id AS anon_1_tableA_id
FROM
  (SELECT tableA.id AS tableA_id
   FROM tableA
   WHERE tableA.deleted IS NOT TRUE
   GROUP BY tableA.id LIMIT %(param_1)s) AS anon_1
JOIN tableA_tableB AS tableA_tableB_1 ON anon_1.tableA_id = tableA_tableB_1.tableA
JOIN tableB ON tableB.id = tableA_tableB_1.tableB
ORDER BY anon_1.tableA_id
```

And here is the query that I need it to generate:

```
SELECT tableB.deleted AS tableB_deleted,
       anon_1.tableA_id AS anon_1_tableA_id
FROM
  (SELECT tableA.id AS tableA_id
   FROM tableA
   WHERE tableA.deleted IS NOT TRUE
   GROUP BY tableA.id LIMIT %(param_1)s) AS anon_1
JOIN tableA_tableB AS tableA_tableB_1 ON anon_1.tableA_id = tableA_tableB_1.tableA
JOIN tableB ON tableB.id = tableA_tableB_1.tableB
WHERE tableb.deleted IS NOT TRUE
ORDER BY anon_1.tableA_id
```

Comment: Is *tableB* not your child in this case? In other words should you not be using [`secondaryjoin=...`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.secondaryjoin). You should consider providing a minimal, **complete**, and verifiable example. Though it is possible to deduce the mapped classes and the query from what you've included, it'd make answering a lot easier if one did not have to.

Comment: Fair point on the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

1. I needed to use the secondaryjoin keyword instead of the primaryjoin
2. I had to figure out the correct way to populate the manual join, namely using the model name for the model and the secondary table name.

`self.db.relationship("tableB",
    secondary='and_(TableBModel.id==tableA_tableB.c.tableB,
                      TableBModel.deleted.isnot(True))',
    secondary=tableA_tableB)`